# Почему не выводится контент при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выводилось содержимое переменной mess. Почему не выводится?

```js
let mess = 'mess'
let text = document.querySelector('.res')
let button = document.querySelector('button')

function res() {

   button.click(function () {
      text.innerHTML = mess
   });
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: Ну во-первых функция не закрыта, во-вторых переменные вне области видимости функции. Точки с запятой в конце строки нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых вам нужно точку с запятой взять в привычку ставить везде.
Во вторых, "клик" у вас был прописан внутри функции, которая не закрывалась и не вызывалась.
В третьих, событие клика должно писаться как `button.onclick = function()...`, а не `button.click(function ()...`

```js
let mess = 'mess';
let text = document.querySelector('.res');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  text.innerHTML = mess;
};
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: "нужно точку с запятой взять в привычку ставить везде" --- почему?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это не относится ко всем разработчикам и в целом к js, это скорее рекомендация тем, кто с кодом пока еще не подружился, ибо, учитывая, что точка с запятой далеко не всегда ставится только в конце строки с кодом, можно накосячить. Например взять тот же цикл `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {...`

Comment: Накосячить можно с чем угодно. Часто встречающаяся ошибка `leght`. Точка с запятой тут не поможет)) И в целом это большая разница - точка с запятой в конструкции языка и "везде" (или как минимум в конце инструкции). Для того же `for` есть документация, в которой чётко описано что должно идти, за чем и чем разделяться. Иначе просто это не валидный синтаксис. Для конца строки таких правил нет. Пример с `for` ещё не понятен тем,что в других конструкциях например используется запятая. Да даже в том же `for` Почему бы не ставить её везде?)) В общем странный совет, пока что ни на чём не основанный))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Действительно, проще подключить тот же Prettier и не мучаться.